# Blender not detecting Radeon graphics card on OpenSuse

Tags: drivers, opensuse, amd-graphics, radeon, blender

I freshly installed OpenSuse on my Laptop, but blender does not seam to detect my Graphics card. I come from Nobrara(Fedora) where everything worked fine as long as I staid on the blender lts 3.3 so I know my card supports hip. I also installed vkbench, which was able detect my card and use it.
Blender Error Edit → Preferences → System → HIP →

> No compatible GPUs found for Cycles Requires AMD GPU with Vega or RDNA
> architecture and AMD driver version 22.10 or newer

These are the infos I got with zypper info

> libdrm_amdgpu1:
> 2.4.115-2.2

> kernel-firmware-amdgpu: 
> 20230320-1.1

Neither of them seam to resemble the version number 22.10, but amd does only offer pro driver for Windows on my card.

System:
OS: OpenSuse Tumbleweed Wayland
GPU: RX 5600M

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to uninstall the zypper version and then manually download the latest Linux version from [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/). Then I moved this into my home folder and added it to my application browser.

Hope this helps